# Use multiplot to plot a contour map and a curve together

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to use multiplot to overlay a curve over a contour map, and here is my gnuplot script.

```
set term postscript enhanced color 'Times-Roman,24'

set output 'cimax_pmf.eps'
set encoding iso_8859_1

set nokey
set xlabel 'RC(\305)'
set xrange [0:12]
set yrange [0.2:1]
set ylabel 'c^2_{imax}'
set y2label 'PMF (kcal/mol)'
set y2range [-20:1]
set multiplot
set pm3d map interpolate 10,10
set view map
set isosamples 10  #increase resolution
set palette rgb 33,13,10   #rainbow color scheme

unset colorbox
splot[0:12][0.2:1] 'cisq_rrr_reduced.dat' u 1:2:3  notitle
unset map

plot[0:12] 'final_pmf.dat' u 1:2 w line lt 2 lw 2 notitle axis x1y2
unset multiplot
```

One thing to mention is that I have two vertical y axis, as suggested by "axis x1y2" in my script. The problem is that after running this script, I found that the second plot does not align with the first plot correctly. In other words, they have different sizes and their overlap seems to be problematic. It looks like the problem described in the first figure of this page
http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/plot3-e.html#5.10

But I cannot solve this problem by using the script similar to that page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am more familiar with multiple plots in or next to each other, but nevertheless two things might help you:

- multiplot allows for "set size" command (see "help set size" for more info) to be used for each graph. But I guess if you say the script on the Not So FAQ page did not help, this is probably not enough.
- It might therefore be useful to set margins (see "help set margin"), which can be used to align more precisely graphs in a multiplot. It also quite often fixes the problem of data ranges of different lengths that cause numerous misalignment problems.

Comment: Thanks. I tried "set origin 0,0" and "set size 1,1" for both figures, and this didn't work. I also tried to let both figures have the same left, right, bottom and top margin, but this didn't work still. Do you  know if there is a better way that I could set the margins?

Comment: Not sure what "does not work". However, you may want to increase the margins a lot to be sure they constrain both graphs. Sometimes with small values, there is no visible effect. Once you get the two graphs aligned, then you can decrease the values of the margin until the multiplot is as large as possible.

Comment: @user2226358: An alternative is to set all margins to 0, `set origin 0.2, 0.2` and `set size 0.79, 0.79` and adjust those values to position the graph and thus adjust the margins.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to use `pm3d` and `multiplot` at all and instead use `plot … with image`. This way, you can do with a single `plot` command.

If I did not make any mistakes, just change your code to (everything before `multiplot` is unchanged):

```
[…]
set y2range [-20:1]
set palette rgb 33,13,10   #rainbow color scheme

unset colorbox
plot\
'cisq_rrr_reduced.dat' w image notitle,\
'final_pmf.dat' u 1:2 w line lt 2 lw 2 notitle axis x1y2
```

Comment: Thank you, @Wrzlprmft. I tried this and this way does not have the alignment problem I described above. However, since the data points in my data file are somewhat sparsely distributed, I still want to use some kind of interpolation such as the "interpolate" keyword in pm3d to increase the resolution of my contour map. Do you know how I can do that when I was plotting with image? I tried "set isosample" and this did not work.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. If you want Gnuplot to interpolate, you have to use `pm3d`. The only alternative is to write a small script that generates an interpolated datafile and plot that file as above.

Comment: Also note that I would never interpolate data for such plots, as it obfuscates the actual resolution of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnuplot's feature of saving contour data to a file via `set table` (see documentation, and rather implicit example [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-300003.7)). Something like:

```
...
set table 'contours.dat'
splot[0:12][0.2:1] 'cisq_rrr_reduced.dat' u 1:2:3  notitle
unset table

plot[0:12] 'final_pmf.dat' u 1:2 w line lt 2 lw 2 notitle axis x1y2, \
           'contours.dat' using 1:2
```

Adjust for your case.